# Why is my IK Bone dragging the mesh with it?

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

[image]

Why is this happening?

I parented the mesh to the two bones on the left site of the IK bone with automatic Weights. My controller pulls it as well though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the *Deform* option for all the controller bones. You should have done that before parenting. Now you'll need to correct the weight of the feet and ankle bones so that they now influence these vertices.

[image]